# Flutter create a raised button

Tags: flutter

I am currently trying to create a custom styled button in Flutter. I wish to create a button similar to this https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hoang8f/android-flat-button/master/screenshot/screenshot.gif

Can I create something similar using RaisedButton or do I need to create it by custom drawing using a CustomPainter? RaisedButton does not seem to create the wanted effect when using the elevation parameter though.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `StatefulWidget` and use the `GestureDetector`

```
  class MyCustomButton extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _MyCustomButtonState createState() => _MyCustomButtonState();
  }

  class _MyCustomButtonState extends State<MyCustomButton> {
    bool _isPressed = false;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return GestureDetector(
        onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) {
          setState(() {
            _isPressed = true;
          });
        },
        onTapUp: (TapUpDetails details) {
          setState(() {
            _isPressed = false;
          });
        },
        child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
              border: _isPressed
                  ? Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 10.0))
                  : null,
            ),
            child: Text("title button")),
      );
    }
  }
```